# Pandas or Numpy, searching, editing and extracting data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, full-text-search

Few weeks ago I started to study python in order to write a programme,
at the moment I try to extract some information from a file, it looks like this:

```html
MAEFILE: benopga1.01.mae
&gen 
igeopt=1 
iaccg=5 
ip160=4 
ifreq=1 
ip24=2 
nogas=2 
iacc=1 
&
&zmat
 C1             18.7209160000            18.5628090000            15.2914270000
 C2             17.4114700000            18.8454610000            15.7184360000
 C3             17.0539910000            18.6449570000            17.0518080000
 C4             18.0032320000            18.1601840000            17.9688000000
 C5             19.3024250000            17.8798070000            17.5452620000
 C6             19.6626680000            18.0820920000            16.2013130000
 H7             18.9985910000            18.7195810000            14.2522760000
 H8             16.6780090000            19.2198900000            15.0089150000
 H9             16.0417370000            18.8626870000            17.3826630000
 H10            17.7239350000            18.0037410000            19.0076080000
 H11            20.0369730000            17.5051670000            18.2535010000
 H12            20.6751990000            17.8633650000            15.8718730000
&
&guess  basgss=6-311g**+ numd=5
    1 Orbital Energy   -11.241317 Occupation  1.000000
 -0.237515017757232 -0.196647289792153 -0.000012299229451  0.000012283693667
 -0.000038832391585 -0.002068759436403  0.000019096186058  0.000035102037517
 -0.000178850142376  0.000386718554923  0.000028243495837 -0.000010189167830
  0.000009719189111 -0.000083379603107  0.000088703347921 -0.000005323744814
  0.000074406344067 -0.000034780134268  0.000042134744869 -0.000025018268285
  0.000005796046950  0.000032438198590 -0.000151512252705 -0.198843760947433
 -0.164626268788198 -0.000032620645254  0.000011142490285 -0.000007071762982
 -0.001751134173474 -0.000117771869441  0.000056795470271 -0.000099889624378
  0.000355125910896  0.000016162939390 -0.000000591018861 -0.000018504072314
 -0.000043258886307  0.000085387104771 -0.000042128218464  0.000032711718420
  0.000062742388095  0.000018426112961 -0.000001087454691 -0.000087393288567
  0.000036394574524 -0.000046738022296 -0.189838829586922 -0.157171079929277
 -0.000027575467355  0.000006987237905  0.000003880133365 -0.001671553419738
 -0.000145911512315  0.000031184688524  0.000049574180168  0.000356303208123
  0.000008457559748 -0.000002555314618  0.000000156292819  0.000001781216751
  0.000074959304234 -0.000076740520986  0.000034291328716 -0.000015539635327
  0.000048978495218  0.000007568809345 -0.000078160169234  0.000017433925123
  0.000021965260595 -0.206688115052246 -0.171120694083044 -0.000024613036749
  0.000000578071180  0.000028857510870 -0.001816148417123 -0.000060499311777
 -0.000017129060142  0.000151731576240  0.000366295601898  0.000027273496960
 -0.000008681030719  0.000003505182219 -0.000084713189897  0.000079444547592
  0.000005268642305  0.000061929650436 -0.000000945876945  0.000025397622782
 -0.000006331576449 -0.000059596946982 -0.000005577539402  0.000100798841928
 -0.249803952550950 -0.206823550176572  0.000003194386460 -0.000011257593014
  0.000044548734829 -0.002165674347528  0.000119312075990 -0.000063891648135
  0.000128577103429  0.000383381470817  0.000015141171971  0.000000035916246
 -0.000018789517620 -0.000044930372579  0.000110215751912 -0.000065285379334
  0.000039159765842  0.000078659142665  0.000027379751909 -0.000029883760840
  0.000089805971123 -0.000055471940289  0.000127658675297 -0.282967668103962
 -0.234291216881311  0.000022041761553 -0.000002823143502 -0.000015098289029
 -0.002411282844625  0.000189683107712 -0.000041945582722 -0.000057757033880
  0.000410957267636 -0.000018584696026  0.000002703022996  0.000011405600689
 -0.000005600032267  0.000119091011558 -0.000113490979291  0.000058095889213
 -0.000027269439738  0.000076776523871 -0.000039022163445  0.000173859295776
 -0.000036395429255 -0.000059944178961 -0.000180764515503  0.000007292236479
 -0.000211164361974  0.000002900643801  0.000006787640262 -0.000032874030369
 -0.000152282839545  0.000001347403058 -0.000192590475337 -0.000022257991946
  0.000010326038114 -0.000016900157341 -0.000145389069678  0.000002334090915
 -0.000184253055893 -0.000026241454432  0.000005721872839  0.000008503996611
 -0.000157846225852  0.000005719915333 -0.000197522897687 -0.000012294624010
 -0.000002547402448  0.000026305673479 -0.000190277091678  0.000012467113833
 -0.000218567465104  0.000019225415536 -0.000011030299816  0.000023682450623
 -0.000214624610593  0.000020667490110 -0.000229289099730  0.000031900177357
 -0.000006901099326 -0.000010189424947

-------
   31 Orbital Energy     0.152723 Occupation  0.000000
 -0.000001484697707 -0.000002021678521 -0.011269736987441 -0.038830417095759
 -0.008858615646339  0.000001192390365 -0.006923508623065 -0.023842815223962
 -0.005418954995446  0.000041590787919 -0.067391763573696 -0.232026052460321
 -0.052998414149352  0.001793328350150  0.000775609630928 -0.002568937981078
  0.003688605910249 -0.001068780674560 -0.006386930085737 -0.000062943108962
  0.199687105918283  0.687684976534009  0.156868067056184  0.000000096154362
  0.000000657329257 -0.011210137098576 -0.038624144508054 -0.008813875928149
 -0.000002083821188 -0.006889998263354 -0.023739788458030 -0.005413447465109
 -0.000018259645012 -0.066955664071598 -0.230792413990635 -0.052580672751758
 -0.003071293835289  0.004370602232574 -0.001299308397285 -0.005372985400140
 -0.002350939654665 -0.002706808510529 -0.000070970422528  0.198318280915318
  0.683514266154416  0.155894609381509  0.000000339923235  0.000001176339340
  0.000304981657499  0.001042477771998  0.000239760902136 -0.000010467863819
  0.000544040658142  0.001845662740944  0.000423422866543  0.000056642800415
  0.000984897727369  0.003286180141148  0.000798961685623  0.000314520592607
 -0.001550492509766  0.001235971917159  0.000362328854063  0.001051946495198
  0.002924677897963  0.000052446885436  0.007592738586630  0.027102621203117
  0.006457030833373 -0.000001674148274 -0.000002569702830  0.011036680737231
  0.038036534353212  0.008683871836959  0.000011681514030  0.006437710430541
  0.022161408213113  0.005042525696551 -0.000073456543616  0.066825871686029
  0.230182549919537  0.052602199705660  0.001619905567722  0.001073249176964
 -0.002693154744685  0.003395235925365 -0.001233638134137 -0.006656299269408
 -0.000031022957851 -0.208382824428751 -0.718837764254747 -0.164641719576342
  0.000002139554361  0.000004317465847  0.010966267617752  0.037792975401876
  0.008624771875724 -0.000011263540804  0.006373597174822  0.021999897758008
  0.005010930775777 -0.000012041105775  0.066365092028384  0.228809219195351
  0.052127667273958 -0.003005259795779  0.004486267413809 -0.001481007618030
 -0.005217612687906 -0.002459044682008 -0.003155753438819  0.000122889172923
 -0.207289443420419 -0.714788889584271 -0.162678954342172 -0.000001113015636
 -0.000001539233415  0.000173647770863  0.000591026047632  0.000138309282669
  0.000001767411845  0.000457220121974  0.001573303489084  0.000360204439751
  0.000025047915999  0.000170009010859  0.000615396416029  0.000093891319707
  0.000532222151981 -0.001708952612925  0.001176730460945  0.000768838272606
  0.001104781032426  0.002758844326405 -0.000048320919224  0.010021022901790
  0.035244457521757  0.007959417545553 -0.000000432884305  0.000043865349832
 -0.000082946240504  0.001226683058023  0.004222389372921  0.000970314215579
 -0.000002541300496  0.000035298825687  0.000101681117207  0.001224755470991
  0.004192362461791  0.000964887073715 -0.000004352857236  0.000035780410422
 -0.000112972423150  0.000059020531435  0.000208544008111  0.000046874782483
  0.000000639601687  0.000054054494787  0.000026791342731 -0.001291902546627
 -0.004454899976684 -0.001026504045236 -0.000006323623792  0.000071261955447
 -0.000128521753658 -0.001293454307352 -0.004429301733713 -0.001017753159295
 -0.000001046054621  0.000011841859973  0.000073751920645  0.000075884640401
  0.000259775657980  0.000060453277266
&
&hess
   1
   1  5.357113E-01
   2 -1.203890E-01  2.050867E-01
   3 -5.072856E-02 -1.224648E-01  7.247686E-01
   4 -2.738767E-01  5.421034E-02  8.516300E-02  6.687076E-01
   5  5.862978E-02 -7.841398E-02 -6.986702E-03 -1.530589E-01  2.102981E-01
   6 -4.882459E-02  2.176720E-02 -1.508757E-01  3.490960E-02 -1.293015E-01
   7  1.397183E-02 -6.213820E-03  3.526196E-02 -1.359815E-01  3.130492E-03
   8 -2.648252E-02  1.165820E-02 -6.485242E-03  1.013400E-02 -7.653658E-02
   9  1.679309E-01 -3.235383E-02  4.798621E-03  6.244518E-03  5.348205E-02
  10 -1.499543E-01  3.053092E-02 -2.007584E-02  7.869050E-02 -3.394869E-03
  11  3.073586E-02 -1.093993E-02  1.498358E-03 -6.620322E-03  4.623322E-03
  12 -2.113264E-02  1.886220E-03 -3.178300E-03 -1.128905E-02  1.402985E-02
  13  1.358396E-01 -2.272879E-02 -9.113526E-03 -6.181379E-02  2.549849E-04
  14 -3.477661E-03  4.127380E-03  1.454523E-02 -3.514229E-04 -6.286993E-03
  15 -7.888047E-02  2.021552E-02 -3.514837E-02  1.840733E-02 -2.058056E-03
  16 -2.177345E-01  7.626153E-02 -1.207416E-01 -3.647403E-02  1.587059E-02
  17  5.247322E-02 -1.002916E-01  7.246352E-02  1.945406E-02  2.204342E-03
  18  2.208958E-02  4.326027E-02 -2.152098E-01 -7.205723E-02  3.178738E-03
  19 -7.725080E-02 -4.733359E-03  7.169356E-02 -1.952258E-03 -5.265493E-03
  20 -4.463521E-03 -4.582251E-02  4.403138E-02  1.752013E-03  3.237253E-03
  21  7.086791E-02  4.407103E-02 -3.203331E-01 -1.998051E-03  2.097618E-03
  22 -1.287577E-02  9.327437E-03 -2.157959E-02 -1.881858E-01  7.230259E-02
  23  2.190754E-03  3.617602E-04  4.639266E-03  7.195528E-02 -7.350281E-02
  24  8.569006E-03 -4.185411E-03  9.161599E-03 -1.241089E-01  6.861581E-02
  25  2.378996E-03  8.676100E-04  2.416760E-03 -4.030590E-03  2.507893E-03
  26  8.991614E-04  6.328556E-03  2.086578E-03 -4.549598E-03  4.186961E-03
  27  1.667829E-03  2.414920E-03 -5.566737E-03  2.914902E-02 -6.879962E-03
  28 -1.480521E-03  2.999713E-04 -7.027812E-04 -1.782413E-03  3.221656E-03
  29  4.484685E-04 -7.341012E-04 -1.860347E-05  3.571517E-03  5.682207E-03
  30 -7.047879E-04 -1.896539E-04  1.144798E-03 -3.791107E-03  2.806446E-03
  31  1.967935E-03  1.052172E-03  2.249519E-03 -1.359768E-04 -4.909666E-04
  32  9.264046E-04  6.619953E-03  2.006525E-03 -5.334520E-04 -4.168043E-04
  33  2.639645E-03  1.762322E-03 -4.896901E-03  1.372681E-03 -4.518228E-04
  34 -1.417455E-02  2.727599E-03  1.044303E-02 -1.172401E-03  3.258573E-03
  35  9.736697E-03  1.617405E-03 -4.499427E-03  3.110862E-03  5.445966E-03
  36 -2.049141E-02  4.551847E-03  9.548502E-03 -3.059820E-03  2.777782E-03
   6
   6  6.148960E-01
   7  9.694602E-02  6.987643E-01
   8  2.440824E-02 -1.503817E-01  2.054470E-01
   9 -2.512768E-01 -7.243872E-02 -8.990523E-02  5.654096E-01
  10 -1.333717E-01 -2.054959E-01  4.717798E-02  3.344556E-02  5.490687E-01
  11  3.904594E-02  7.187216E-02 -9.645819E-02  3.823231E-02 -1.192375E-01
  12 -5.054405E-02 -1.138194E-01  6.829035E-02 -2.021683E-01 -6.795284E-02
  13  1.102332E-01 -5.969411E-02  3.723179E-02 -1.236615E-01 -2.349015E-01
  14 -3.853905E-03  1.553892E-02  2.601743E-03  3.184075E-03  6.357285E-02
  15 -6.782885E-02 -6.726040E-03 -5.407333E-03  8.467873E-02  1.300986E-02
  16  3.943401E-03 -4.511242E-03  1.382113E-03 -2.390661E-02  1.119908E-02
  17 -2.094158E-02  1.540967E-03 -9.168102E-03  2.639755E-02 -2.632153E-02
  18  1.416749E-01 -2.532995E-02  2.683847E-02 -1.501283E-01  1.674068E-01
  19  2.808227E-02 -4.818105E-03  3.094910E-03  2.058231E-03 -1.745043E-03
  20 -6.667732E-03  2.870215E-03  6.262360E-03  5.683060E-04  4.427648E-04
  21 -5.175332E-03  2.554751E-03  4.579300E-04  1.979747E-03 -7.062836E-04
  22 -1.247529E-01  8.258119E-03 -3.432272E-03  8.252649E-03  2.144433E-03
  23  6.881531E-02  3.750150E-03  1.833843E-03  1.047128E-03  4.236422E-04
  24 -1.804521E-01 -2.291255E-02  1.036880E-02 -1.292029E-02  3.004725E-03
  25 -1.907067E-03 -3.063512E-01  5.888514E-02  8.248172E-02 -1.394043E-02
  26  2.208861E-03  5.925325E-02 -5.117732E-02 -1.285134E-02  9.154041E-03
  27 -3.215292E-03  8.194643E-02 -1.255761E-02 -8.551740E-02 -1.995845E-02
  28 -3.296838E-03  9.060765E-03  2.748152E-03 -2.084458E-02 -7.728528E-02
  29  2.687659E-03 -4.066922E-03  1.111791E-03  9.587301E-03 -4.752476E-03
  30 -7.099807E-04  8.960116E-03  1.031423E-03 -1.388900E-02  7.175752E-02
  31  1.691020E-03 -4.691846E-03  2.565325E-03  3.394495E-03 -1.317085E-02
  32 -4.306708E-04  2.862186E-03  6.076609E-03  2.204974E-04  2.751124E-03
  33 -5.486880E-04  2.398883E-03  4.941632E-04  1.520535E-03  8.765089E-03
  34 -3.900191E-03  1.185306E-03 -4.557608E-04 -8.504399E-04  2.324262E-03
  35  3.027231E-03 -4.660645E-04 -6.058911E-04  5.406380E-04  1.162152E-03
  36 -1.076955E-03 -6.065414E-04  3.749918E-04 -1.651439E-03  1.559582E-03
  11
  11  2.036463E-01
  12 -1.172782E-01  7.186272E-01
  13  3.836605E-02  9.833300E-02  6.189527E-01
  14 -8.124822E-02 -7.237159E-03 -1.586210E-01  2.107532E-01
  15  2.604649E-03 -1.440396E-01  4.110175E-02 -1.227296E-01  6.810652E-01
  16 -4.998799E-03  3.558635E-02 -1.517975E-01  2.806294E-03  7.703362E-02
  17  1.156440E-02 -7.570831E-03  2.908585E-02 -7.398307E-02  3.881048E-02
  18 -3.234759E-02  6.717726E-03 -5.807469E-02  4.951787E-02 -2.832498E-01
  19  3.589195E-04 -4.708646E-04 -1.402206E-03  3.220279E-03 -3.065811E-03
  20 -6.839957E-04 -2.250234E-04  3.431037E-03  5.450787E-03  2.657729E-03
  21 -2.501729E-04  1.105759E-03 -3.591744E-03  2.836891E-03 -9.231576E-04
  22  9.591988E-04  2.154412E-03 -1.186699E-03 -4.080684E-04  1.491628E-03
  23  6.348418E-03  2.082719E-03 -5.469945E-05 -4.309774E-04 -5.945081E-04
  24  1.834672E-03 -5.234314E-03  1.275562E-03 -5.273805E-04 -1.623391E-04
  25  2.339952E-03  1.011159E-02 -6.364443E-04  3.209197E-03 -3.830418E-03
  26  5.936686E-04 -4.692742E-03  3.085246E-03  5.692126E-03  3.099157E-03
  27  4.112008E-03  9.641439E-03 -3.333572E-03  2.835538E-03 -1.490121E-03
  28 -4.639572E-03  7.112198E-02 -2.059962E-03 -5.057039E-03  2.904566E-02
  29 -4.581722E-02  4.419494E-02  2.063191E-03  4.243199E-03 -6.499605E-03
  30  4.385196E-02 -3.204086E-01 -1.279372E-03  2.454236E-03 -5.470362E-03
  31  9.879408E-03 -2.202778E-02 -1.887970E-01  7.219524E-02 -1.241630E-01
  32  1.443492E-03  5.036378E-03  7.235257E-02 -7.357053E-02  6.847109E-02
  33 -4.034273E-03  8.875759E-03 -1.249539E-01  6.886918E-02 -1.800114E-01
  34  9.205108E-04  2.151887E-03 -3.251011E-03  2.100621E-03 -1.955914E-03
  35  6.472624E-03  2.166082E-03 -4.961588E-03  3.187735E-03  1.801821E-03
  36  2.475965E-03 -5.392252E-03  2.780805E-02 -7.027603E-03 -3.239105E-03
  16
  16  7.058893E-01
  17 -1.554764E-01  2.072989E-01
  18 -5.616458E-02 -9.217960E-02  5.520851E-01
  19  8.981009E-03  3.289528E-03 -2.141664E-02  7.626286E-02
  20 -3.842831E-03  2.156460E-03  1.000977E-02  2.846781E-03  3.642322E-02
  21  9.319906E-03  1.309879E-03 -1.410448E-02 -7.646282E-02 -4.860829E-02
  22 -4.402991E-03  2.531367E-03  3.289913E-03  9.021696E-04 -1.251841E-03
  23  2.725604E-03  6.274671E-03  1.628016E-04 -1.156805E-03 -3.268124E-03
  24  2.537554E-03  5.855487E-04  1.563713E-03 -7.394921E-04 -6.175566E-04
  25  1.026188E-03 -3.997980E-04 -7.437612E-04 -2.657211E-04  1.335569E-04
  26 -2.275656E-04 -6.403373E-04  4.661607E-04 -2.089260E-04  2.334557E-04
  27 -8.333180E-04  4.056932E-04 -1.539848E-03  1.552873E-03 -2.872954E-04
  28 -4.991017E-03  2.960965E-03  2.222760E-03 -2.021511E-05 -3.472167E-04
  29  2.739691E-03  6.103553E-03  3.149083E-04 -3.757001E-04 -1.056348E-03
  30  2.773596E-03  4.162969E-04  2.059696E-03  1.871311E-05 -1.472036E-04
  31  8.389904E-03 -3.707522E-03  7.624896E-03  3.256189E-04 -1.070285E-04
  32  3.342920E-03  8.529872E-04  1.309502E-03  2.234428E-04  9.689788E-05
  33 -2.246703E-02  9.836860E-03 -1.293489E-02 -1.083503E-03  6.089104E-04
  34 -3.062399E-01  5.922308E-02  8.165886E-02  5.042012E-04 -1.375289E-03
  35  5.927026E-02 -5.126865E-02 -1.257008E-02 -1.443801E-03 -3.563906E-03
  36  8.262465E-02 -1.283576E-02 -8.543201E-02  3.426350E-04 -1.115803E-03
  21
  21  3.374350E-01
  22 -2.145991E-04  1.952296E-01
  23 -7.899096E-04 -7.886814E-02  6.658415E-02
  24  2.434416E-04  1.327314E-01 -7.490323E-02  1.874819E-01
  25 -1.504871E-04  1.714452E-04 -1.179780E-03 -2.325636E-04  3.220066E-01
  26  1.568302E-04 -1.102295E-03 -3.573059E-03 -1.099444E-03 -6.529751E-02
  27 -3.836369E-04 -5.860705E-04 -8.976903E-04  1.021072E-03 -8.867881E-02
  28  1.218173E-05  3.024906E-04  2.516389E-04 -1.141836E-03  4.239541E-04
  29 -1.441930E-04 -1.026389E-04  8.840927E-05  6.332547E-04 -1.291296E-03
  30 -1.374519E-04  3.812079E-04  2.389330E-04 -8.747765E-04 -1.502824E-04
  31  3.851771E-04 -1.639111E-04 -1.356532E-04 -3.111450E-04 -7.902321E-04
  32  1.182647E-04 -2.347572E-04 -1.084055E-03 -1.576438E-04  2.115227E-04
  33 -7.593839E-04 -1.667396E-04 -1.008961E-04 -1.123286E-05  5.825404E-04
  34 -2.035376E-04 -8.011347E-04  3.153121E-04  4.611029E-04 -1.316073E-04
  35 -9.809362E-04  5.440663E-04  6.513052E-05 -1.662642E-04 -2.997207E-04
  36  5.655858E-04 -1.044500E-03  2.754315E-04  3.638921E-04  5.800512E-05
  26
  26  4.236930E-02
  27  1.211680E-02  8.569162E-02
  28 -1.245167E-03  5.853340E-04  7.688814E-02
  29 -3.211526E-03 -1.073037E-03  3.035872E-03  3.637004E-02
  30 -9.073261E-04  5.569719E-04 -7.721346E-02 -4.840140E-02  3.370049E-01
  31  5.516888E-04 -1.052577E-03  7.862359E-04 -1.339463E-03 -2.253878E-04
  32  8.382047E-05  2.822024E-04 -1.251478E-03 -3.643525E-03 -9.503755E-04
  33 -1.807402E-04  3.462591E-04 -6.238417E-04 -7.053561E-04  3.763429E-04
  34 -3.067637E-04  5.290655E-05 -2.494180E-04  1.374706E-04 -1.399704E-04
  35 -1.022331E-03 -2.811845E-04 -2.047648E-04  2.343184E-04  1.575352E-04
  36 -2.816129E-04  2.140399E-05  1.520584E-03 -2.731030E-04 -3.847069E-04
  31
  31  1.959794E-01
  32 -7.942207E-02  6.628383E-02
  33  1.329428E-01 -7.483048E-02  1.873301E-01
  34  1.308904E-04 -1.106336E-03 -1.028018E-04  3.222324E-01
  35 -9.751806E-04 -3.283255E-03 -1.006349E-03 -6.565566E-02  4.251950E-02
  36 -6.224509E-04 -9.048575E-04  1.125719E-03 -8.805915E-02  1.207815E-02
  36
  36  8.527950E-02
&
```

I did try to use pandas to look through the file and the extract in a separated file, what is bellow &zmat. I mean lines C1 to H12

```html
import os 
import pandas
import numpy

os.chdir ("D:\\Ubuntu\downloads")
dt =pandas.read_fwf ("ga1.01.in", header =None, sep = '\s+')
```

Unfortunately pandas only see two columns and I can not got further.
I plan to do the same for the lines bellow &hess. 
Which is the lower par of a symmetric matrix.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u05ZE.png
```

In this case 36x36, but it is saved by 5 columns, while the rows are enumerated. I still working in a solution once I am able to extract that part, I assume that pandas is a good election for that issue. if someone can give me a idea where to start , I would appreciate ane help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this line for reading lines C1 to H11 with options to skip first 11 rows, read 12 lines and specify the extents of fixed-width fields of each line.

```
dt =pandas.read_fwf ("ga1.01.in", header =None, skiprows=11, nrows=12, colspecs=[(0,5), (12,35), (36,61),(62,91)])
```